# How Can I Recover PHP $_SESSION variables from within Objective-C / iOS?

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, networking, network-programming

I have some PHP scripts on a server that return cookies, html code, etc. that interact with an iOS app that I have been working on. Things like login, send item, receive item, etc.

Problem is maintaining a persistent connection. I figured we'd use cookies, and that PHP "start session" would allow us to access $_SESSION variables via the cookie. However, I'm not able to find any of the session data returned in the cookie, other than the Session ID.

I thought I could use the Session ID + a key to grab elements from off the PHP session array by calling a script from within the app. The app isn't the problem so much:

I need to know where the $_SESSION variables actually ARE so I can USE them. That may sound facetious, but that is what I need.

If I start a session, then do something like:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$_GET['username']
```

Shouldn't I be able to return the variable set for that session using the following:

```
$session_id = $_GET['session_id'];
$key = $_GET['key'];

function getSessionValue($session_id, $key) {
    session_start($session_id);
    return $_SESSION[$key];
}

echo getSessionValue($session_id, $key);
```

Something isn't working...I appreciate any and all help! Thanks :D

Comment: what network library are you using (on the iOS side of things)?

Comment: Technically that should work unless the session has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `session_start()` [does not take any parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). So, stating a Session ID there won't help.

Secondly, by default PHP use cookie to store the Session ID in a variable named `PHPSESSID`. PHP will set this variable when you first access the page. Make sure you always add this cookie variable (with the same value that PHP set) when making requests to the server.

The default storage for the cookies are files. The location of the files is set in `session.save_path` variable in PHP configuration. On Ubuntu, the default location is `/var/lib/php5`

When a request comes with `PHPSESSID` variable set in the cookie, calling `session_start()` wil make PHP take the cookie value and read the coressponding session file and then set the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: I'm a bit late getting back to this but thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a DB based session?

Or MAYBE this will work:

```
function getSessionValue($session_id, $key) {
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', $session_id);
    session_start($session_id);
    return $_SESSION[$key];
}
```

Or

Maybe this is a domain issue? 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php